# boost::program_options validation per argument instead of per argument type?

Tags: c++, boost-program-options

`boost::program_options` appears to support some level of [custom validation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/program_options/howto.html) but it seems odd to me that the validation is written in terms of types, and not per-argument, and I'm wondering if I'm missing something here.

For example, say you have a "file editing" program that takes `input` and `output` filenames from the command line. Next assume that you want to store these into variables of type `boost::filesystem::path`. Now, let's say we have a requirement that the `input` file **must** exist, but the `output` file doesn't (i.e. if the `output` file doesn't exist, we'll create it.) Ideally, we'd have a way to test that the `input` argument exists, and separately that the `output` file either exists and is writable or is in a directory that we can write to. (The specific differences here aren't actually relevant. This applies to any situation where you're using the same type in multiple places where you'd like to have different validation rules depending on the use.)

Because we configure validators by creating overrides of `validate` (which are presumably found at compile time by their type signatures, it appears we can only have one validator for all instances of `boost::filesystem::path`. I've seen the `notify` hook, but the signature of those callbacks has a `const` qualifier, so it doesn't seem like you could modify the value, and it's not clear in the documentation how `throw`ing in a `notify` callback would get worked in to the validation system.

This seems like a pretty fundamental limitation to the point where I think I'm probably missing something. Am I? Thoughts?

Comment: You can wrap up your parameter into its own type.

Comment: This is harder than it sounds. For instance, boost::filesystem::path has many constructors to manually write passthroughs for. I tried using C++11 constructor inheritance, but there appears to be some fundamental incompatibility between that feature and the various meta-programming in boost::program_options. In the abstract, it also feels wrong to foist what is effectively context-specific runtime complexity (i.e. complexity in my usage of `program_options`, not in it's capabilities) off onto the type system.

Comment: There is no need to implement constructors except for default. Wrapper type is only required to make conversion work and should not be used outside of parameters handling code (extern code should receive base type).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It never hurts to have one type per concept in a program. If the two paths represent different concepts, give them their own types:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

namespace po = boost::program_options;
namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

template<class Type, class Tag>
struct tagged
{
    Type const& get() const { return value_; }
    Type& get() { return value_; }
    operator Type& () { get(); }

    friend decltype(auto) operator>>(std::istream& is, tagged& t) {
        return is >> t.get();
    }

    friend decltype(auto) operator<<(std::ostream& os, tagged const& t) {
        return os << t.get();
    }

    // and so on...

    Type value_;
};

using bar_path = tagged<fs::path, class bar_path_tag>;
using foo_path = tagged<fs::path, class foo_path_tag>;

int main()
{
    bar_path bar;
    foo_path foo;

    po::options_description desc("prog");
    desc.add_options()
    ("foo", po::value(&foo), "a foo path")
    ("bar", po::value(&bar), "a bar path")
    ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put per-option validation logic into a [notifier](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost/program_options/typed_value.html#idp682515264-bb) callback.